# Digital signal in my circuit is too noisy

Tags: voltage, digital-logic, noise, signal

I have a very simple digital circuit which I built with 74LS chips. Basically, the Q output of a JK flip flop is fed into a chip in another prototype board through a connector about 30 cm long (the only one I could find ).
The problem is that the signal at the end is too noisy, as I checked disconnecting the cable and probing with my oscilloscope the signal diretcly from the JK flip flop.
Is there any way to reduce the noise ?

Comment: Can you show us the waveform at each end of the cable? Also a photo of the cable and connectors.

Comment: also, there's open-collector outputs on some 74xx ICs, in case you have one of these. I'll go with: without atleast knowing the exact ICs involved and a picture, this will remain impossible to answer with any certainty. One could speculate, but that would be of less help to you than if you added more info :)

Comment: Is it so noisy that it isn't working properly? Or, are the waveforms just not as perfect as you think they should be?

Comment: I am sorry unfortunately i can't take pictures at the moment. :( yes it does NOT work as it should. Basically, at the end of the cable I get the right signal only here and there for a brief moment, the rest of the time it is at 0 V . The connection is fine, there is no loose connection

Comment: Is the ground connection fine as well?  The two ends of the connection must have a common ground, and that needs to be low resistance to avoid noise.

Comment: I checked with a multimeter and every connection is fine. The signal should have a period of about 26 microseconds . Maybe at that frequecies the cable is too long and creates interferences? I dunno...

Comment: A digital signal with a TTL level should not cause measurement problems. It is more likely that you have not connected the oscilloscope correctly. Slightly longer cables can receive any interference as antennas. Check for interference even when the power is off. If so, fix the cables and connections first.

Comment: Question is too vague. But one way to reduce noise, depending on the context, might be to replace 74LS with 74HC.

Answer (score 0):

For 74LS, you need VDD bypass capacitors across 7/14 or 8/16 of each IC. With no more than 1/8" leads to the bypass cap, 0.01UF or 0.1uF.

And ensure the GROUND wire between your two trouble points is WIDE, such as copper braid.

And, finally, insert 100 ohms at the signal source of your troubled wire. Maybe 150 or 220 ohms.